# parse json.net vb.net INSTAGRAM

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I´ve been reading some posts but I need help.

I'm trying to parse a json String (text_) like this...

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/....",
    "next_max_id": "000000000000_000000"
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "attribution": null,
      "tags": [
        "socialmedia",
        "linkedin"
      ],
      "type": "image",
      "location": {
        "latitude": 0.000000,
        "longitude": 0.0000000      },
-----------
```

I use json.net

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

And the code is...

```
    text_= webClient_IGR.DownloadString("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" & id_igr & "/media/recent?access_token=" & IGR_KEY)

    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(text_)
    MsgBox(json.SelectToken("pagination").SelectToken("next_url"))
```

I have no problem but 
How can I get the value from tags or location?

Excuse me for my english.

Please, help me!

Comment: `Dim tags = json("data")(0)("tags").ToArray` should work to get the tags, the location parts: `myLat = json("data")(0)("location")("latitude")` the 0 represents the data item you want to look at (there is only 1 in the post)

Comment: Great!!! The code works. A lot of thanks Plutonix!